# Which OpenAL 3D distance model should I choose (migration from FMOD)?

Tags: c++, macos, openal, fmod

I'm migrating from FMOD to OpenAL and I really need to know how to make OpenAL sound more like FMOD.

From what I have gathered, by default FMOD uses a logarithmic distance model (like in rl) and it seems that there is no exact analogue in OpenAL. Judging by formulas in the OpenAL documentation, the default *Inverse Distance Clamped Model* seems like most suitable, however I'm not so sure.

What would you guys recommend?